# react-beautiful-dnd with horizontal and vertical directions combined

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd, react-sortable-hoc

I searched everywhere but couldn't find the right answer. Maybe I'm not good enough at operating Search Engines ️.

Can `react-beautiful-dnd` combine both horizontal and vertical directions? Like what `react-sortable-hoc` can easily do with `axis="xy"`.

Comment: I think you can make use of dragging across multiple lists feature to accomplish this as specified here https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/Multi-List-Drag-and-Drop-With-react-beautiful-dnd-Immer-and-useReducer

Answer (score 0):

As of now library doesn't provide any support for xy axis, that's the biggest con for this library.